# How can I access to: ToString()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I receive this to.String:

```
{
  "message": "5"
}
```

from this code

```
res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log (body.toString());   
  });
});`
```

How can I get the element "5"? Thanks

Comment: `body.message` ?

Comment: Show me "Undefined"

Comment: `JSON.parse(body).message` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're getting body.toString as

```
{
    "message": "5"
}
```

You can access "5" as

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body).message)
```

Comment: Show me "Undefined"

Comment: Try parsing the body as JSON.parse(body)